# Use Drupal's Default Views Filter Handler on "Pseudo" Views field?

Tags: views, 8, plugins

How do I use Drupal's core [Views filter handler plugins](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21filter%21FilterPluginBase.php/group/views_filter_handlers/8.7.x) on a custom views field?

I have a custom field which has its own FieldPluginBase Class. Does not have a DB query.

**MYMODULE.views.inc**:

```
/**
* Implements HOOK_views_data().
*/
$data['table']['date_field'] = [
  'title' => t('Date Field'),
  'field' => [
    'id' => 'date',
  ],
  'filter' => [
    'id' => 'date',
  ],
];
$data['table']['custom_field'] = [
  'title' => t('Custom Field'),
  'field' => [
    'id' => 'custom_field',
  ],
  'filter' => [
    'field' => 'date',
    'id' => 'boolean', // <--
  ],
];
```

How do I use this core views filter with a "pseudo field"?

Comment: You can't use that particular core filter, it's exclusively based on the database - you'll need to create your own filter plugin. Extending the current one as a starting point is definitely an option, but you'll need to override the various methods which plug it into the DB (at least `query()`)